# Query to fetch minimum id from a table with duplicate records

Tags: sql, oracle

There is a tableA.

| Source | Legacy_Address_ID | City | State_Code | Pincode | ADR_LINE_1 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| C | T173005029 | LANCASTER | PA | 17602 | N LIME ST |
| S | 84191 | LANCASTER | PA | 17602 | N LIME ST |
| S | 10020 | SAINT CLAIR SHORES | MI | 48081 | MILE RD |
| C | 85230429169 | SAINT CLAIR SHORES | MI | 48081 | MILE RD |
| C | 8770211698 | JOLIET | IL | 60434 | PO BOX 666 |
| S | 9348710 | JOLIET | IL | 60434 | PO BOX 666 |

The records in the table are basically having the same City,state, pin, adr_line_1 but different Legacy_Address_IDs. I want the output as below :

| Legacy_Address_ID | New_Legacy_Address_ID |
| --- | --- |
| T173005029 | 84191 |
| 85230429169 | 10020 |
| 8770211698 | 9348710 |

Basically the min address id(having source S) as new_legacy_Address_id and the larger (having source C) as legacy_address_id.

I tried

```
select * 
from 
    (select 
         legacy_address_id, 
         min(legacy_address_id) over (partition by adr_line_1, city, state_code, pincode 
                                      order by legacy_address_id) as new_legacy_address_id 
     from 
         tableA)
where 
    legacy_address_id <> new_legacy_address_id;
```

This query returns as output:

| Legacy_Address_ID | New_Legacy_Address_ID |
| --- | --- |
| T173005029 | 84191 |
| 85230429169 | 10020 |
| **9348710** | **8770211698** |

The last record is not returned properly. Can someone please help me out?

Comment: There needs to be another column which keeps track of which of the two duplicate addresses came "first" and which came "last."

Comment: What is wrong with the last row?  Looks like `Legacy_Address_ID` is a char string column. So `'9348710' > '8770211698'` is true.

Answer (score 1):

Use a `PIVOT`:

```sql
SELECT Legacy_Address_ID,
       New_Legacy_Address_ID
FROM   tablea
PIVOT (
  MAX(legacy_address_id)
  FOR source IN (
    'C' AS Legacy_Address_ID,
    'S' AS New_Legacy_Address_ID
  )
)
```

or, conditional aggregation:

```sql
SELECT MIN(CASE source WHEN 'C' THEN Legacy_Address_ID END) AS Legacy_Address_ID,
       MIN(CASE source WHEN 'S' THEN Legacy_Address_ID END) AS New_Legacy_Address_ID
FROM   tablea
GROUP BY City, State_Code, Pincode, ADR_LINE_1
```

or, using conditional aggregation with analytic functions:

```sql
select * 
from   (
  select legacy_address_id, 
         min(CASE source WHEN 'S' THEN legacy_address_id END) over (
           partition by adr_line_1, city, state_code, pincode
         ) as new_legacy_address_id,
         source
  from   tableA
)
where  source = 'C';
```

Which, for your sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE tablea (Source, Legacy_Address_ID, City, State_Code, Pincode, ADR_LINE_1 ) AS
SELECT 'C', 'T173005029',  'LANCASTER',          'PA', 17602, 'N LIME ST'  FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'S', '84191',       'LANCASTER',          'PA', 17602, 'N LIME ST'  FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'S', '10020',       'SAINT CLAIR SHORES', 'MI', 48081, 'MILE RD'    FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'C', '85230429169', 'SAINT CLAIR SHORES', 'MI', 48081, 'MILE RD'    FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'C', '8770211698',  'JOLIET',             'IL', 60434, 'PO BOX 666' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'S', '9348710',     'JOLIET',             'IL', 60434, 'PO BOX 666' FROM DUAL;
```

All output:

> | LEGACY_ADDRESS_ID | NEW_LEGACY_ADDRESS_ID |
> | --- | --- |
> | 8770211698 | 9348710 |
> | T173005029 | 84191 |
> | 85230429169 | 10020 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=4c657e3e34fd3f01670a8a89e7422234)*